# PJSIP iOS Error

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pjsip

I am implementing the pjsip in one of my project and It's the first time I am working on VOIP. Actually the problem with me is I am not able to figure out the steps to use the PJSIP code in my application. I have compiled the pjsip and Integrated into my app. But after I add the account with pjsip method, my server developer said *I need to send auth in next attempt* and I am not able to figure it out How do I do that. Please find my code and responce from it.

```
 pj_status_t status;
pjsua_acc_id acc_id;

// Create pjsua first
status = pjsua_create();
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_create()", status);

// Init pjsua
{
    // Init the config structure
    pjsua_config cfg;
    pjsua_config_default (&cfg);

    cfg.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
    cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
    cfg.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;

    // Init the logging config structure
    pjsua_logging_config log_cfg;
    pjsua_logging_config_default(&log_cfg);
    log_cfg.console_level = 4;
    log_cfg.level = 5;
    // Init the pjsua
    status = pjsua_init(&cfg, &log_cfg, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error in pjsua_init()", status);
}

// Add UDP transport.
{
    // Init transport config structure
    pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5060;

    // Add TCP transport.
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
}

// Add TCP transport.
{
    // Init transport config structure
    pjsua_transport_config cfg;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&cfg);
    cfg.port = 5080;

    // Add TCP transport.
    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, &cfg, NULL);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error creating transport", status);
}





// Initialization is done, now start pjsua
status = pjsua_start();
if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error starting pjsua", status);

// Register the account on local sip server
{
    pjsua_acc_config cfg;
   // cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);
    cfg.cred_count = 1;
    cfg.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("*");
    cfg.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
    cfg.cred_info[0].username = pj_str(sipUser);
    cfg.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    cfg.cred_info[0].data = pj_str(password);
    cfg.ice_cfg_use=PJSUA_ICE_CONFIG_USE_DEFAULT;

    pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg);

    char sipId[MAX_SIP_ID_LENGTH];
    sprintf(sipId, "sip:%s@%s", sipUser, sipDomain);
    cfg.id = pj_str(sipId);

    char regUri[MAX_SIP_REG_URI_LENGTH];
    sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", primary);
    cfg.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);

    pjsip_endpoint* endpoint = pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt();
    pj_dns_resolver* resolver;


    struct pj_str_t servers[] = { pj_str(primary) };
    pjsip_endpt_create_resolver(endpoint, &resolver);
    pj_dns_resolver_set_ns(resolver, 1, servers, NULL);





    status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS) error_exit("Error adding account", status);



}
```

Then it return the error, please find below

```
17:02:30.936    pjsua_acc.c  ....IP address change detected for account 0 (xxx.xxx.x.34:5060 --> xxx.xxx.xx.3:5060). Updating registration (using method 4)
17:02:30.942 sip_auth_clien  ...Unable to set auth for tdta0x101176c00: can not find credential for d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141/Digest
17:02:30.942    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration error: No suitable credential (PJSIP_ENOCREDENTIAL) [status=171101]
17:02:31.312   pjsua_core.c  .RX 737 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=45424 (rdata0x101171428) from UDP xx.xxx.xx.111:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Full response of **status = pjsua_acc_add(&cfg, PJ_TRUE, &acc_id);**

```
17:02:23.460 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.2.1 for POSIX initialized
17:02:23.463 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
17:02:23.465          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x101156a28)
17:02:23.466 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
17:02:23.466 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
17:02:23.466   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
17:02:23.466 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
17:02:23.466 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
17:02:23.466 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
17:02:23.466 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
17:02:23.467 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
17:02:23.467 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
17:02:23.467 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
17:02:23.524 coreaudio_dev.  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz
17:02:23.524 coreaudio_dev.  ..core audio initialized
17:02:23.524          pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x10116d428)
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
17:02:23.549 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
17:02:23.549   pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
17:02:23.550   pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.2.1 for iOS-10.3.1/arm-iPhone7,1/iOS-SDK-7.1 initialized
17:02:23.550   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
17:02:23.551   pjsua_core.c  SIP UDP socket reachable at xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060
17:02:23.551 udp0x1008a5690  SIP UDP transport started, published address is xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060
17:02:23.552    tcplis:5080  SIP TCP listener ready for incoming connections at xxx.xxx.x.xx:5080
17:02:23.552   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
17:02:23.552 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
17:02:23.552   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
2017-05-30 17:02:23.553998+0530 MangoVoice[580:58635] Warning: Libinfo call to mDNSResponder on main thread
17:02:23.555    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141
17:02:23.556    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141 added with id 0
17:02:23.556    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 0: setting registration..
17:02:23.559   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 586 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=45424 (tdta0x101176c00) to UDP xxx.xxx.xx.111:5060:
REGISTER sip:xxx.xxx.com SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjzsVCERQi7e0oTiyjeP1VcxrybJOBV3eT

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=ePz39uBlCOl2fQc7ZCKUxzF69RuasBjW

To: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>

Call-ID: WGh6WZa6sUjf8d2w.XfD-U4fx9kndxPE

CSeq: 45424 REGISTER

Contact: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;ob>

Expires: 300

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
17:02:23.559    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 0: Registration sent
17:02:30.930   pjsua_core.c  .TX 586 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=45424 (tdta0x101176c00) to UDP xxx.xxx.xx.111:5060:
REGISTER sip:xxx.xxx.com SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjzsVCERQi7e0oTiyjeP1VcxrybJOBV3eT

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=ePz39uBlCOl2fQc7ZCKUxzF69RuasBjW

To: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>

Call-ID: WGh6WZa6sUjf8d2w.XfD-U4fx9kndxPE

CSeq: 45424 REGISTER

Contact: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;ob>

Expires: 300

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
17:02:30.935   pjsua_core.c  .RX 737 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=45424 (rdata0x101171428) from UDP xxx.xxx.xx.111:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKPjzsVCERQi7e0oTiyjeP1VcxrybJOBV3eT;received=112.196.29.3

From: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=ePz39uBlCOl2fQc7ZCKUxzF69RuasBjW

To: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=Fp60emvSDBrgN

Call-ID: WGh6WZa6sUjf8d2w.XfD-U4fx9kndxPE

CSeq: 45424 REGISTER

User-Agent: MangoVoice

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE

Supported: timer, path, replaces

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141", nonce="28a8625e-d168-4462-97f8-1a244a5b0243", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
17:02:30.936    pjsua_acc.c  ....IP address change detected for account 0 (xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060 --> 112.196.29.3:5060). Updating registration (using method 4)
17:02:30.942 sip_auth_clien  ...Unable to set auth for tdta0x101176c00: can not find credential for d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141/Digest
17:02:30.942    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration error: No suitable credential (PJSIP_ENOCREDENTIAL) [status=171101]
17:02:31.312   pjsua_core.c  .RX 737 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=45424 (rdata0x101171428) from UDP xxx.xxx.xx.111:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP xxx.xxx.x.xx:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKPjzsVCERQi7e0oTiyjeP1VcxrybJOBV3eT;received=112.196.29.3

From: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=ePz39uBlCOl2fQc7ZCKUxzF69RuasBjW

To: <sip:Xb3253592824b8a8ded0@d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141>;tag=Fp60emvSDBrgN

Call-ID: WGh6WZa6sUjf8d2w.XfD-U4fx9kndxPE

CSeq: 45424 REGISTER

User-Agent: MangoVoice

Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE

Supported: timer, path, replaces

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141", nonce="28a8625e-d168-4462-97f8-1a244a5b0243", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
```

Comment: Did you get any luck with this ?

Comment: If you didn't solve this issue can you tell us what is the value of `status` for this line `status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &cfg, NULL);` please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try  using pjsua_acc_config_default(&cfg) before setting any setting in cfg. As you are telling it to use digest scheme then you are changing the cfg with default it is not sending auth info in reply of 401 response